# VB script to insert a macro into an excel file

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

There are certain cases we need to insert a macro into the excel sheet programatically. I have found a VB script that will insert a specific macro into the mentioned excel sheet.

Comment: Well done......

Comment: @jamheadart I just made the required modifications accordingly and since I couldn't find any thread related to this functionality I posted this here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
strPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 
excelLocation = strFolder & "\GeneratedReport.xls"
macroVBSLocation = strFolder & "\sendMailModule.bas"
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelLocation)
       objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import macroVBSLocation
objWorkbook.Save
objExcel.Quit
```

excelLocation points to the location where excel will be present. 
macroVBSLocation points to the location where macro will be present.

Comment: How does that translate to [tag:powershell]?

Comment: @user11217663 It would be something like this :  

`$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

$sheet = $excel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelLocation)
$excelmodule = $sheet.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

$macroscript = @"put the code for macro in here"@

$excelmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString($macroscript)`